# "<QRandomGenerator> No such file or directory" error with static QT build

Tags: c++, qt

I took the source code of "Threaded fortune" the project from the link specified in the documentation:

[Link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html)

With build got following error:

```
<QRandomGenerator> No such file or directory
```

Yes, used google search engine. Yes, saw `QRandomGenerator` docs.

```
Header: #include <QRandomGenerator>
qmake:  QT += core
Since:  Qt 5.10
Inherited By:   
QRandomGenerator64
```

BUT. My kit's Qt version is 5.9.9 as i builded it with static key from 5.9.9 version sources:

[Link](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.9/)

So, my question is: is it possible to use it in any way with my Qt version or is there any substitution for `QRandomGenerator` to get same\similar functional?

Comment: You can try copying the source code of that into your project.

Comment: There is an example of Threaded fortune that works with Qt-5.9: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html)

Comment: @drescherjm thank you. It worked for me. You can change this comment to answer if you want.